# Why do dual-SIM smart phones always have to have 1 SIM card turned on?

Tags: sim-card, dual-sim

I read that smart phones can operate for Wifi messaging apps, for example, without needing a SIM card, except during installation

But when I go to Settings /Connections /Sim Card Manager on my **dual SiM card** Android smart phone, why do I get the error "can't turn off this sim card" when trying to turn off SIM 1 after turning off SIM 2?

[image]

Comment: Regular single SIM phones also have always one active asIM card (as there is no option to disable the one and only SIM card). If you want to disable both SIM cards use Air plane mode.

Comment: Waiting for answer still, since that's just an observation. But anyway, airplane mode cuts off wifi in the process, despite have nothing to do with the capabilities of a SIM card, so it is not an answer that explains the phenomenon inquired.

Comment: On recent Android (or Pixel?) phones Air plane now only affects cellular network. WIFI stays as it is. This change was introduced by Google a few weeks ago.

Comment: On earlier phones, the WIFI and Bluetooth do turn off, but you can enable just the WIFI after turning on airplane mode.

Comment: Also, not all Wifi apps will work without a sim, such as whatsapp.

Comment: Before SIM installation, whatsapp wont work. After, or if SIM plan expires or SIM turned off, whatsapp still works. Still need answer to op's question.

Comment: Doesn't Airplane Mode count as turning both SIM cards off? Why must 1 SIM card have to be turned on on Android, yet Airplane Mode does turn both SIM cards off?